# Force daemon to a specific hard fork version

Tags: monerod, hard-fork

I want my node to stay on the v6 hard fork and reject all new blocks from later versions. Is there a command to force my node to stay on that specific hard fork version or do I need to compile and run an old version of the daemon?

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove version 7 and 8 from the testnet fork table near the top of src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp (the last two lines as of this time).
You will have to pop blocks first till v6 with the current binary (monero-blockchain-inmport --testnet --pop-blocks N), then make that change.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that. I was looking for a solution that doesn't require changing the code.

Comment: Well, you can use --offline while still on v6, and avoid mining. That might be enough for your purposes.